# Javascript clearInterval works only for one setInterval on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

In a object (assembly) I have two properties (check & blipbg)

I fire 2 setInterval for each one of them.

And when I call clearInterval on each one only one works : clearInterval(assembly.checkinterval);

clearInterval(assembly.blipinterval); does not work and, randomly, continues to run for several cycles and stop, or runs indefinitively.

Scope problem ? But why one is working then ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var zipli = $('.zipli');
        var actionlink = $('.actionlink');
        var zip_asset_url = $('.asseturl');
        var csrftoken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
        var zip_status_url = $('.statusurl');


        zipli.on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            zipli.html('<a href="" class="waitlink">Demande de création de fichier zip - Ne fermez pas la fenêtre');
            zipli.addClass('disabled');

            assembly.order();

        });


        assembly = {};

        assembly.order = function(){
            $.ajax({
                context: this,
                url: zip_asset_url,
                type : "POST",
                data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken},
                success: function (resp) {

                    assembly_url = resp.assembly_url;

                    zipli.html('<a href="" class="waitlink">Fichier zip en cours de création - Ne fermez pas la fenêtre');
                    waitlink =  $('.waitlink');

                    assembly.checkinterval = setInterval(assembly.check,1000);
                    assembly.blipinterval = setInterval(assembly.blipbg,1000);

                    console.log("assembly.order success"+resp);
                },
                error:function(resp){
                    $('.waitlink').html("Erreur lors de la demande de création d'archive - Rechargez la page ?");
                    console.log("assemby.order error"+resp);
                }
            });
        };

        assembly.blipbg = function (){
            $('.zipli a').animate({'color': '#eee'}, 500).animate({'color': '#999'}, 500);
        };

        assembly.check = function(){

            $.ajax({
                context: this,
                url: zip_status_url,
                type : "POST", // http method
                data: {assembly_url:assembly_url,csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken},
                success: function (resp) {

                    if (resp.ok == "ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED"){
                        clearInterval(assembly.checkinterval);
                        clearInterval(assembly.blipinterval);

                        zipli.remove();
                        $('.zipul').html('<li class="pull-right"><a href="" class="finallink"> Fichier zip prêt : Téléchargez</a></li>');
                        $('.finallink').attr("href",resp.results.archive[0].ssl_url);

                    }
                    else if (resp.error){
                        console.log("assembly.check resp.error error : %o", resp);
                        clearInterval(assembly.checkinterval);
                        clearInterval(assembly.blipinterval);

                        $('.waitlink').html("Erreur lors de la préparation de l'archive : "+resp.error).animate({'color': 'red'}, 300);

                    }else{
                        console.log("zipnoready");
                    }

                },
                error:function(resp){
                    $('.waitlink').html("Erreur lors de la vérification du process: %o", resp);

                }
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a scope problem in this case, but that the reference IDs are overriden by several calls to order().

IDs are unique and the setInterval which run in the background has to have *its* id clear.

If order() is called there is a risk of the old id is overridden so that clearInterval will only clear the most reason timer while the old will still run.

Consider using callbacks instead to avoid this situation.

Comment: Callback did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call setInterval, call clearInterval.

```js
clearInterval(assembly.checkinterval);
assembly.checkinterval = setInterval(assembly.check,1000);
clearInterval(assembly.blipinterval);
assembly.blipinterval = setInterval(assembly.blipbg,1000);
```

Comment: I believe the question mentions, that the OP is trying to clearInterval.

Comment: Understand that. What I am suggesting is the OP clearInterval before another setInterval is called. I am thinking the setInterval line is called multiple times before a clearInterval is called.